# Score cutoff settings for "unanswered"

Tags: support

I couldn't find an answer to this when I searched the help pages.

I was working with a user who posted an unfavorably-received question (current score -6), and tried to help clarify what they were looking for (as well as providing an answer). I should note that, at this point, the question is still open.

I was surprised when I looked over the posts without an accepted answer (i.e., clicked "Unanswered", and couldn't see the post.

I am assuming that there's a cut-off point - that, when a question's vote total falls below a certain level, it no longer shows up on the default searches (i.e., the lists of questions you can get by clicking an option at the top of the page.

I can find it by searching, and via recent inbox messages, so it is still there.

I wondered what exactly is the cutoff point where negatively scored message are no longer seen on the default searches (I'd assume -5, but I always prefer not to assume), and if there's any setting on our accounts that would allow us to apply a different default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions are hidden from the homepage when their score is -4 or less. (On meta sites, it is -8 or less). [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769).

Such questions are **not** hidden from the `/questions` pages, however.  Compare:

- [Newest unanswered questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/unanswered/)
- [Newest questions, no filter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)